# Any way to see search insights for low volume keywords on Google Trends or Something SImilar?

Tags: statistics, google-trends

Google Trends generally works great for me, But recently I noticed that Low volume terms show "Not enough Data"
Is there a way to see even if there's 1 search?

Answer (score 0):

It is intentionally not possible to see data for any single user activity.
That would potentially allow to identify the user.

From [Google Trends FAQ](https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4365533?hl=en):

> Google Trends does filter out some types of searches, such as:
>
> - Searches made by very few people: Trends only shows data for popular
>   terms, so search terms with low volume appear as "0"